# Using parameters from command line in a system command

Tags: c, unix, system, reverse

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
main(int argc,char *argv[]){
int i,j;
for (i=0;i<argc;i++){
printf("Name: %s\n",argv[i]);
    char name[100];
    sprintf(name,"echo"| rev, argv[i]);
    system(name);

}

};
```

I have this, my question is how do I reverse the file with the name stored in argv[i],
what i want, is to execute a child process that does this command "rev argv[i]"?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, please use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` (and check the return value to determine if truncation occurred).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you need to change the line `sprint()`

```
sprintf(name,"rev %s", argv[i]);
```

Well, you should do that on the right parameters too, doing it on all might not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer to modify the changes in file ? Something like "sprint(name,"rev %s>%s",argv[i])" ?

Answer (score 3):

You've got the right idea to use `sprintf`. But it needs a format specifier just like `printf` does. And `|` is a bitwise OR operator which makes no sense here (it would yield a *mutilated* pointer if it were even defined).

```
snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "rev %s", argv[i]);
```

---

If you want to modify the file whose name is in `arg[i]`, you can't just redirect the output into the same file, because the shell (used by `system` to execute the command) opens both files simultaneously and opening a file for writing truncates its length. So you'll need to redirect the output into a different file and then copy back over the original in a separate command.

```
snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "rev %s > %s.modified", argv[i], argv[i]);
system(name);
snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "mv %s.modified %s", argv[i], argv[i]);
system(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your usage of sprintf

it must be with a string, which shows something impure !!
check with the same.